# Redis Sentinel Configuration not working

Tags: redis, config, redis-sentinel

I am trying to set up sentinel using two redis nodes. Please find inline the conf file.

port 16371

dir "C:\Program Files\Redis\16371\"

loglevel notice

logfile "C:\Program Files\Redis\logs\16371.log"

sentinel monitor ExampleMaster 127.0.0.1 6371 1

sentinel down-after-milliseconds ExampleMaster 3000

sentinel failover-timeout ExampleMaster 6000

When I am trying to run server with this configuration I am getting following error:

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 5

```
    'sentinel monitor ExampleMaster 127.0.0.1 6371 1'
    Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

Can someone help me to fix this. TIA :)

Answer (score 1):

quarom needs to be min 2

sentinel monitor ExampleMaster 127.0.0.1 6371 2

Comment: I think it is ok if you have quorum as 1, I will recommend to run redis in sentinel mode. same issue was faced for MAC OS i tried following and it worked

`redis-sentinel /path/to/config --sentinel`

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved. I was missing auth-pass entry in redis-sentinel. Second I noticed in redis 6.0.6 that the auth-pass entry should mentioned behind the **monitor** line and the service become started